# how to correctly read text file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read `file.txt` that looks like this:

```
%b jjj 123

%%% 4 5 6

%%%
s 1 2 s
t 3 2 f
p 2 2 f

i 0 9 e
%%%
u 3 3 e
```

I'm using `pandas` so I did

```
>> pd.read_table('file.txt',comment="%", header="None", names=["c1","c2","c3","c4"])
        c1  c2  c3  c4
0  s 1 2 s NaN NaN NaN
1  t 3 2 f NaN NaN NaN
2  p 2 2 f NaN NaN NaN
3  i 0 9 e NaN NaN NaN
4  u 3 3 e NaN NaN NaN
```

It's clearly wrong. This is what I'm trying to get

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  s   1    2   s
1  t   3    2   f
2  p   2    2   f
3  i   0    9   e
4  u   3    3   e
```

Comment: maybe consider read line by line

Comment: Use `sep=r'\s+'`, default looks for commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just add in `sep=' '` to make sure that it reads spaces as the delimiter:

```
df = pd.read_table('file.txt', sep = ' ', comment="%", header=None, names=["c1","c2","c3","c4"])

>>> df
  c1  c2  c3 c4
0  s   1   2  s
1  t   3   2  f
2  p   2   2  f
3  i   0   9  e
4  u   3   3  e
```